# python recursion over 10000 nodes

Tags: python, recursion, memory-management, depth-first-search, large-data

I have a list of over 10000 items and using recursion i want to iterate over all the possible combinations of their selection  starting from 1st item for both its selection and not selection ( 2 branches ) then deciding on 2nd item for each branch and so on till last item in DFS way.
I am using this code for optimization and most of the branches are not iterated over but atleast 1 leaf will be reached as to find the best

the problem is I made a recursion code in python and it works fine for 1000 elements after changing recursion limit to 10000 but i cant get it work for 10000 elements no matter how much i increase the recursion limit.( though i read its not suggested )

I am new to python and kind of feel like I am making some space assignment fault in my code that its not working . Please help me in any fixes or alternatives

Here is my recursion function

def rep(i):
    global taken
    global Btaken
    global Tvalue
    global Tweight  
    global Bestimate
    global Bvalue
    global count
    global Mcount   
    count+=1    
    Tweight -= items[i].weight
    if Tweight>=0 :
        taken[items[i].index-1] = 1 
        Tvalue += items[i].value    
        if i < len(items)-1:
            rep(i+1)
        else :
            Btaken=taken*1
            Bvalue = Tvalue     
        Tvalue -= items[i].value                
        taken[items[i].index-1]=0   
    Tweight += items[i].weight      
    Bestimate = best(i+1,Tweight)
    if Bestimate+Tvalue > Bvalue :  
        if i < len(items)-1:
            rep(i+1)
        else :
            Btaken=taken*1
            Bvalue = Tvalue 
    if Mcount<count :
        Mcount=count    
    count-=1

The Mcount value is also correct now showing the number of functions in the call ( or hold) currently (according to dfs the height of tree ) then why when i increase the recursion limit to over 15000 still i cant use it to interate for 10000 items, I need some guidance on python memory limits .

Comment: [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) does exactly what you want.

Comment: wow python has built in functions for sort and combinations. I am using this for solving Knapsack problem and hence I cant determine the number of elements i need in iteration before run time. It will become lengthy this way.

Comment: Yes it does. And if you want to write a DFS on a huge tree, you should use an explicit stack and iteration to avoid stack overflow.

Comment: In that case - i.e. using it for Knapsack which is known to be a hard problem I would try to implement something that is more of Branch and Bound (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) or Dynamic programming

Comment: I am using branch and bound only. using DP for 10000 items and 1000000 capacity will not work :C. can you suggest any rework on my code, right now trying to figure out why for 1000 items this Mcount value is  27000+

Comment: Strange now the Mcount value is 1000 only according to DFS when i added "print "decounting",i,count,Mcount,Tweight,Tvalue,Bvalue " after  count+=1 and count-=1 respectively and its showing correct value for different inputs as well, incorrect Mcount must be because of some indentation fault, damm python is difficult... but fun

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar Using explicit stack for above worked for 10000 nodes. Thanks :D