# Recursion in python over 10000 elements

Tags: python, recursion

I am new to python and want to use branch and bound for knapsack problem, and my code is running fine for 1000 elements when I increase the recursion limit but dosent work for 10000 elements no matter how high recursion limit i set

Why does this code crosses the recursion limit, the Mcount value shows 10000 only which means its not storing more than 10000 nodes of data in its recursion stack. I think I am missing something but cant figure out what.

```
def rep(i):
    global taken
    global Btaken
    global Tvalue
    global Tweight  
    global Bestimate
    global Bvalue
    global count
    global Mcount   
    count+=1    
    Tweight -= items[i].weight
    if Tweight>=0 :
        taken[items[i].index-1] = 1 
        Tvalue += items[i].value    
        if i < len(items)-1:
            rep(i+1)
        else :
            Btaken=taken*1
            Bvalue = Tvalue     
        Tvalue -= items[i].value                
        taken[items[i].index-1]=0   
    Tweight += items[i].weight      
    Bestimate = best(i+1,Tweight)
    if Bestimate+Tvalue > Bvalue :  
        if i < len(items)-1:
            rep(i+1)
        else :
            Btaken=taken*1
            Bvalue = Tvalue 
    if Mcount<count :
        Mcount=count    
    count-=1
```

Comment: It's impossible to interpret code like this that makes such heavy use of global variables without knowing what those variables contain. Can you show the initial values for them, and for `items`? Oh, and what is `best`? Surely you could refactor this algorithm to use fewer globals, which might also help you see where it is going wrong on the recursion.

Comment: First: There are more stack frames than the ones you're counting, even if you're counting correctly (and I don't think you are). Second: Stop trying to solve this by increasing the recursion limit. It won't work. The people who responded [the last time you asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344612/python-recursion-over-10000-nodes) told you what to do: use an explicit stack and an iterative algorithm instead of recursion. Increasing the recursion limit only turns a Python stack overflow into a C stack overflow.

Comment: @Blckknght : Sorry for no information on global variables, I started python about 10 days ago only and used simpler codes to make sure my work is done. and yes I will learn about refactor and use it in future thanks.

Comment: @user2357112 : thanks for reminding me about explicit stack again... actually my node count value is correct but the implicit stack was not limited by just the number of nodes in a path from root to leaf, and further recursions increased it over recursion limit ...   thanks again I finally made a python code for EXPLICIT STACK and it works like a charm for even 10000 nodes.